# Help Identifying Bag of Black and Grey Lego pieces from set 11021

Tags: piece-information

My son got box of Classic Lego (set 11021) that came with extra unmarked bags of Lego pieces.  Here is one of the bags, can you help identify which one this is?

Thank you!

[image: Help Identifying Bag of Black and Grey Lego pieces from set 11021]

Comment: This bag is from the same set as your other question : https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/17523/mystery-bag-of-blue-and-green-lego-pieces

Comment: I just noticed you already mentioned set 11021. For clarification : the 3 bags from your 3 questions came with that set.

Comment: I emailed the customer support and they provided me with this answer: "We intentionally don't include building instruction for these bags for your LEGO® 11021 because we want builders to let their imaginations run wild! For inspiration, we added some pictures to show a few things that can be built with the pieces in the set. Copying the models pictured can be incredibly rewarding before moving on to building more amazing creations."