# Mystery Bag of Blue and Green Lego pieces

Tags: set-identification

Can you help with identifying this bag of Lego pieces?

Thank you!

[image: Mystery Bag of Blue and Green Lego pieces]

Comment: Two of your other questions are about bags from the same set : https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/17522/help-identifying-bag-of-black-and-grey-lego-pieces-from-set-11021 , https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/17525/tan-and-white-lego-help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on

- Lime Plate 2 x 3
- Blue Plate 2 x 10

This is [also](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/17522/help-identifying-bag-of-black-and-grey-lego-pieces-from-set-11021) from [11021-1 90 Years of Play](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=11021-1)

[image: 11021-1 90 Years of Play]

Comment: You are correct, thank you for replying.

I emailed the Lego customer support and they provided this answer:

"We intentionally don't include building instruction for these bags for your LEGO® 11021 because we want builders to let their imaginations run wild! For inspiration, we added some pictures to show a few things that can be built with the pieces in the set. Copying the models pictured can be incredibly rewarding before moving on to building more amazing creations."