# Tan and White Lego Help

Tags: set-identification

Can you help me figure out which set this belongs to?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: This bag is from the same set as your other question : https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/17523/mystery-bag-of-blue-and-green-lego-pieces

Comment: I emailed the customer support and they provided me with this answer:

"We intentionally don't include building instruction for these bags for your LEGO® 11021 because we want builders to let their imaginations run wild! For inspiration, we added some pictures to show a few things that can be built with the pieces in the set. Copying the models pictured can be incredibly rewarding before moving on to building more amazing creations."